# Multiple input value on form submit

Tags: javascript, html

```
<input type="text" name="Amount" value="100" size="20" maxlength="10" id="textfield7" class="required">
```

If i click on submit button i want the value to be multiplied by 100.
is there any way to do this by javascript???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short:

```
<form onSubmit="document.getElementById('textfield7').value *= 100;">
```

Cleaner:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function multiply(){
  var field = document.getElementById('textfield7');
  field.value = parseInt(field.value) * 100;
}
</script>
<form onSubmit="multiply();">
```

Comment: <form onSubmit="document.getElementById('textfield7').value *= 100;">   this one worked for me... thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function multiply(){
var val= document.getElementById("textfield7").value;
var newval= val*100;
alert(newval);
}
</script>

<input type="text" name="Amount" value="100" size="20" maxlength="10" id="textfield7" class="required" />
<input type="submit" onClick="multiply();"/>
```

Comment: Right...but the event has to be assigned to the button and not the text field. And if the button is actually working as a 'submit' button, the correct event would be onsubmit.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply **write the correct value already multiplied by 100** in the input field. :)

If for any reason this can't be done I would simply do:

```
<form onsubmit="this[0].value*=100;">
    <input type="text" name="Amount" value="100" size="20" maxlength="10" id="textfield7" class="required">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var submitButton = document.getElementById("submitButtonId");
submitButton.onclick = function (e) {
  var inputAmount = document.getElementById("textfield7");
  var calculatedAmount = parseInt(inputAmount.value, 10) * 100;
  // do what you wish with calucatedAmount, such as returning false if you don't want to submit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but under any normal circumstances it would be the wrong way. Do the math in the server-side code. It is pointless to take even a small risk of getting wrong data (when some data arrives without having been processed by client-side JavaScript).